# Javascript display innerHTML on the same page

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, display, permute

So I am testing the permute function of D3.js and it works just fine.
The issue I am having is to display the results on the same page using innerHTML, it always reloads in order to display.
I am probably missing a detail here, can someone help?

permute.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function* permute(keys) {
    var size = keys.length,
        c = Array(size).fill(0),
        i = 1;
    yield keys;
    while (i < size) {
        if (c[i] < i) {
            var k = i % 2 && c[i];
            [keys[i], keys[k]] = [keys[k], keys[i]];
            c[i]++;
            i = 1;
      yield keys;
    } else {
      c[i++] = 0;
    }
  }
}

function showPermutations(){
    var input = document.getElementById("keys").value;
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=input;
    for (var words of permute(input.split(/\s+/))) {
        document.write(words.join(''));
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
</script>

<body>
  <form>
    <label><b>Keywords</b></label></br>
    <input type="text" id="keys" name="keys"></br>
  </form>
    </br>
<input type="submit" value="Permute" onclick="showPermutations();"></br>
<p><span id='results'></span></p>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of you pointed out the issue is caused by the submit button, but in this other example, using submit, the JS works just fine on the same page:

test.html

```
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing I can see is that you are not closing your `<head>` tag.. ;)

Comment: thanx, edited. But that is definitely not whats causing the issue:)

Comment: With your edit you now have a `<body>` tag inside the `<head>` tag. That's invalid. Anyway, if you don't want to submit input elements, don't put them inside a `<form>` tag.

Comment: Or prevent the form from being submitted, rather than `<input type=“submit” />` use `<button type=“button”>`?

Comment: <input type=“button” /> wont work either

Comment: Well no, but that’s not what I suggested.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica sorry, I meant <button type=“button”> :)

Answer (score 0):

When you click the submit button, the page will automatically reload. You should prevent that by calling the `preventDefault` method of the event object that is passed to the event handler, in your case, that handler would be `showPermutations`.

Make that function receive one argument, called `e`, `ev`, or `event` (as it is normally called) and inside it, execute the `preventDefault` method before anything else.

```
function showPermutations(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

Or don't use a submit button.

Comment: "_When you click the submit button, the page will automatically reload._" Not true when the button is not inside a form, which seems to be the case here. Also `preventDefault` will only work on a submit event, not on a click event.

Comment: I used function the argument  showPermutations(e){ console.log(typeof e.preventDefault); .. but still it wont work. Using button instead of submit wont work either. You can copy and paste the code to a html file and try it out. Any ideas?